# Word for equivalence preserving transformations of equations

Tags: terminology, relations, equivalence-relations

I am searching for a mathematical term describing an algebraic manipulation of an equation which preserves equivalence. So while adding $2$ to both sides of an equation results in an equivalent equation, squaring both sides does not. In German, there is the word "Äquivalenzumformung" (literally: equivalence transformation). Is there a similar word in English?

(Sorry for the stupid tags, didn't find anything better)

Comment: I know of no such word. I'm the first to admit that I don't know everything, but that fact coupled with how long this question has been sitting around suggests that English probably doesn't have a word for it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I find this interesting, because a word like this is actually pretty useful: "Since we made only 'Äquivalenzumformungen', the initial result also holds.", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is funny but it doesn't seem like English mathematical language has a generally used term for this because the concept is definitely very obvious.

I suggest that  **'equivalence *preserving* transformation'** is sufficient. It doesn't sound strange, even though usually in such circumstances where this would be used, 'transformation' by itself would be the usual term.